# How to show image in firebase push notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to display image in push notification in flutter. I have image url in my message object from server, using this url I want to diaply image in both android and iOS device. How can I do this in flutter. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you implemented this? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for notifications you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications this package

check it out showBigPictureNotification() https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the firebase doc regarding images here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

There is a limit of 300KB for images and additional quote limits if Cloud Storage is used.

Comment: yes I have read the document and I am not using Cloud Storage, Image stored in my server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the inbuilt functionality in the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package.

All you need to do is set image in the notification payload along with other values like ***body*** or ***title*** etc.

references : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image
and https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded

Answer (score 0):

I will be mostly focussing on IOS integration for Image Push Notification using Remote Notification JSON from FCM. Before we start, go through these links if you have not yet started implementing Image Push Notification.

**Firebase Project & Android Initial Setup :**
[Firebase & Android Initial](https://Firebase%20Project%20&%20Android%20Initial%20Setup%20:%20https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-flutter-app/)

**IOS Initial Setup: (Don’t implement Advanced Section yet)** [IOS Setup](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/)

The steps to look out for are described below => (Advanced, Optional) Allowing Notification Images:

Add a notification service extension

- From Xcode top menu go to: File > New > Target…
- A modal will present a list of possible targets, scroll down or use the filter to select “Notification Service Extension”. Press Next.
- Add a product name (use ImageNotification to follow along), set Language to Swift and not Objective-C and click Finish.
- Enable the scheme by clicking Activate.

Add target to the Podfile

- Add following lines at the last of ios/Podfile file:

```js
target 'ImageNotification' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
   pod 'GoogleUtilities'
 end
```

- Install or update your pods using pod install from the ios and/or macOS directory.

Use the extension helper

- Open Xcode and from the navigator select your ImageNotification extension.
- Open the NotificationService.swift file.
- And just copy the following code to your NotificationService.swift file.

```js
//
//  NotificationService.swift
//
//  Created by Abhinav Kumar Sintoo
//

import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    
    private var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    private var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        defer {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent ?? request.content)
        }

        guard let attachment = request.attachment else { return }

        bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}
extension UNNotificationRequest {
    var attachment: UNNotificationAttachment? {
        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["image_url"] as? String, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: attachmentURL)!) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? UNNotificationAttachment(data: imageData, options: nil)
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    convenience init(data: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) throws {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let temporaryFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let temporaryFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(temporaryFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: temporaryFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        let imageFileIdentifier = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
        let fileURL = temporaryFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        try self.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
    }
}
```

- The above code basically downloads the image when a notification comes. Max notification image size is 300KB.
- Open project in Xcode > Select Runner from navigator > select ImageNotification from the top centre tab where Runner is > and run the project by selecting a device. It will ask you to select the project once you run the project with this selection Choose an app to run: select the app with which it needs to run.
- After running the extension stop the task and then select Runner and run the app.

**And then the last step:**

Calling FCM API to send the notification to the device:

```js
curl --location 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' \
--header 'Authorization: key=ServerKey' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "registration_ids": ["messagingId1","messagingId2"],
    "priority": "high",
    "content_available": true,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "Offer!",
        "image_url": "https://proshort.ai/static/img/ps_logo.png",
        "image": "https://abhinav/img/ps_logo.png"
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "hello",
        "body": "Enter your message",
        "sound": "default",
        "image": "https://proshort.ai/static/img/ps_logo.png"
    }
}'
```

Body Of Post Request: [Remote Notification JSON](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages)

- Use the above link to make the JSON as per your requirements, you just have to make sure that:
- data key should have an image_url parameter for IOS devices to show Image Push Notification. data is actually for both Android & IOS, check this link for the behaviour. [Image Notification Payload Parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload)
- notification key should have an image parameter for Android Devices.